# Is it possible to insert a small matrix in to a big matrix in to a desired location?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I have to insert a small matrix into a big matrix (zeros matrix), I was trying through a loop, but every time I am getting the value error: could not broadcast the input array from the shape (6,6) into shape (4,4)

there are two issues:-

1. how to insert it into the zeros matrix. (specifying the location into the big zeros matrix).
2. how to put that matrix, from the 23rd row of the 40*40 zeroes matrix.

```
import numpy as np

ndofs = 39

k = np.array(  [  [   1,         0,        1,       0,          0,          0 ],
                  [   0,         12,       6,       0,        -12,          6 ],
                  [   0,         6 ,       4,       0,         -6,          2 ],
                  [   1,          0,       0,       1,          0,          0 ],
                  [   0,        -12,      -6,       0,         12,          6 ],
                  [   0,          6,       2,       0,         -6,          4 ] ] )

K = np.zeros((ndofs+1,ndofs+1))
print(K.shape) 

# for each element, changes to global coordinates

for i in range(ndofs):
    K_temp = np.zeros((ndofs+1,ndofs+1))
    K_temp[3*i:3*i+6, 3*i:3*i+6] = k
    K  += K_temp


print(K)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just overwrite the indexes in the bigger array...

```
a = numpy.zeros((50,50))
b = numpy.ones((10,10))
a[2:12,2:12] = b # insert b at 2,2
```

Comment: sir, is it possible to place the numbers of the arrays at desired positions by giving each number/integer of the array an address.

something like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHQf9.jpg 

the upper matrix is obtained output and the lower matrix is desired one.